# Can I create an hemi-cycle raising signal with one pin and the other hemi-cycle signal with another pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, library, pins, system-design

[image: graph related the question]
I am new to Arduino, I would like to know if someone could help me to create this type of signal with the Arduino Uno. Many thanks!!

Comment: I'd use an [MCP4822](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP4822).

Comment: the arduino does not have analog output per se ... it is a PWM output ... please clarify what pin 9 and pin 10 signify in the diagram ... what is the purpose of the signal

Comment: it is to create an induced magnetic field in coils and stray currents. It is for an electrochemical project. Yes!! I know you cannot generate an analog output but if it is similar to the sketch would be OK. The pins 9 and 10 are I want to use, so the pin 9 and ground and the pin 10 and ground.

Comment: it is unclear how pin 9 and pin 10 are used ... if pin 9 and pin 10 are analog outputs, then you should draw two separate waveforms

Comment: Yes!! you are right, my fault it is unclear, they are two different waveforms superimposed